# ASP.net mvc does not validate submodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have two mvc models

```
public class Model1
{
    [Required]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Model2
{
    public Model1 ValidateThis {get;set;}
    public Model1 DoNotValidateThis {get;set;}
}
```

In postback I fill both properties ValidateThis and DoNotValidateThis. I want to validation occurs only on ValidateThis property.

Comment: what kind of validation do you want?

Comment: You would have to create a separate model for `DoNotValidateThis` or you may be able to use "conditional validation."  Try googling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit more research I chose next solution which works just fine for me. In controller i put next code for validation.

```
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(
        model2obj.ValidateThis,
        new ValidationContext(model2obj.ValidateThis, null, null), results,true);

        ModelState.Clear();

        foreach (ValidationResult validationResult in results)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ValidateThis." + validationResult.MemberNames.First(), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The default model binder does not support this. You will have to implement your own model binder:

- Create a new attribute, `DoNotValidateMeAttribute`
- Create a new model binder that, when doing model binding, checks to see if the `DoNotValidateMeAttribute` is present and, if not, does model binding without validation.

Then you would annotate your model like this

```
public class Model2
{
    public Model1 ValidateThis {get;set;}

    [DoNotValidateMe]
    public Model1 DoNotValidateThis {get;set;}
}
```

Googling "Custom model binders in ASP.NET MVC" should get you started. Be aware, though, that this will probably turn out to be a non-trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `IValidatableObject` interface on Model2

```
public class Model2 :  IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```